# How to resolve 'ImportError: No module named marionette_test'

Tags: python, marionette, firefox-marionette

In my Python script I am trying to set some phone settings through Marionette driver. I am importing the following:

```
from marionette_driver import By
from marionette_driver import Wait
from marionette import Marionette
```

Then I am attempting to open a client session with the device:

```
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828)
client.start_session()
```

However, I am receiving UnknownCommandException:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz.py", line 30, in <module>
    client.start_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver/decorators.py", line 26, in _
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver/marionette.py", line 1243, in start_session
    body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver/decorators.py", line 26, in _
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver/marionette.py", line 741, in _send_message
    self._handle_error(err)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver/marionette.py", line 765, in _handle_error
    raise errors.lookup(error)(message, stacktrace=stacktrace)
marionette_driver.errors.UnknownCommandException: WebDriver:NewSession
```

FYI, I am using marionette-driver 1.1.1

Any suggestion regarding resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

---

Edit on 10/26/2018

It is returning a different error message now:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from marionette import Marionette
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xyz.py", line 7, in <module>
    from marionette import Marionette
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .marionette_test import (
ImportError: No module named marionette_test
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to an outdated driver as answered here: [WebDriver Error New Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507431/selenium-webdriver-crashes-webdrivererror-newsession-after-about-70-seconds)

- You can download the lastest from the Github [Mozilla Repo](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

If it is not Repo relate then it could be because **.pyc** files linger and python tries to use them first before recompiling.

- Basically you would find the relate **.pyc** files and remove then so the source is recompiled. Check this [open bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1321468) for more info.

Thank you. Good day.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I updated my `geckodriver` as per the accepted answer on the thread. But it did not solve my problem. I am now receiving `ImportError: No module named marionette_test`

Comment: Hello,
 There is mention that [ https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1321468 ] could help by running some "clobber python" command to get rid of old .pyc files. Thank you. Good day.