# Selenium WebDriver crashes (WebDriverError: newSession) after about 70 seconds

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm baffled by this new error that started happening to my existing, working project, even though I didn't make any changes to code to cause this to happen (but it might have been due to a FireFox update, or to a dependency suddenly failing). After it started happening, I did add the catch to help debug what was causing the sudden quit:

```
var prom = new Builder()
  .forBrowser('firefox')
  .build()
prom.catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
let driver: WebDriver = await prom
```

Basically, when my code gets to the last line of this code block, it pops up a FireFox window, waits about 70 seconds (should have fulfilled the promise by now), and then throws an error, which heads to the catch and logs it to the console:

```
{ WebDriverError: newSession
    at Object.throwDecodedError (\path\to\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (\path\to\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (\path\to\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:468:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  name: 'WebDriverError',
  remoteStacktrace: 'WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5\nUnknownCommandError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:472:5\ndespatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:290:13\nexecute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:271:11\nonPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:246:15\nonPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:245:8\n_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9\n' }
```

Funny thing is, when inspecting the WebDriverError object using Visual Studio, it says it has a message property of "newSession" that for some reason doesn't get logged to the console (or stringified when I try that).

Anyways, the error is poorly constructed because "newSession" doesn't tell me anywhere near enough information to track down what is going wrong.

Can anyone help me determine what it is waiting the ~70 sec for?

**UPDATE**:
I determined the web request that it is waiting on (a POST to `http://localhost:51290/session`, where the port varies on each run). It is this request that times out after 70 seconds. I can duplicate this timeout in an external application (e.g. SoapUI) by sending `{}` to the URL (which also pops up a firefox window). However, if I set the timeout in SoapUI to something enormous, the JSON response is, of course:

```
{"value": {
   "error": "unknown error",
   "message": "newSession",
   "stacktrace": "WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5\nUnknownCommandError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:472:5\ndespatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:290:13\nexecute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:271:11\nonPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:246:15\nonPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:245:8\n_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9\n"
}}
```

I'm thinking I will need to debug the FireFox side of this, can anyone get me started on that?

Comment: I have the exact same issue…

Comment: @chitzui I knew I wouldn't be alone... are you also using FireFox?

Comment: yes, it happens with firefox…

Comment: think I figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution to that issue. My Geckodriver was outdated. Updating the GeckoDriver resolved the issue.

On OSX What I had to do was:

```
brew uninstall geckodriver
```

and then

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm facing somewhat similar issue: `(node:65725) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnsupportedOperationError: newSession: Not Found`. Do you happen to know? For context, I'm using BrowserStack with their local capabilities (hitting a local server that's running on my machine).